# Tell RVM to recheck ruby version on git checkout

Tags: ruby, git, bash, rvm

I'm using RVM and setting the ruby version in my Gemfile. Because I'm currently working on upgrading my app to a new version, I have branches with different versions.

Every time I switch to or from these branches, I've been doing `cd.. && cd project_directory` to get RVM to notice the change and switch versions. This is a bit of a nuisance. Is there a way I can get RVM to do this automatically when I check out a branch?

Failing that, is there at least an RVM command that does this?

**Edits:**
I've now spent far too much time digging into this, and discovered a few things:

Thanks to **Xavdidtheshadow**, I've written a git post-checkout hook which, as the name suggests, will execute stuff when I checkout a branch. Here it is:

**project_directory/.git/hooks/post-checkout:**

```
echo 'Checking for updated Ruby version'
cd .
```

Now the problem is, this doesn't work. Oh, it'll echo the string just fine, but it doesn't trigger RVM rechecking the ruby version. I've learned that RVM [defines its own `cd` function](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/master/scripts/cd). Sadly, I'm not particularly adept at shell scripting, so I'm a little hazy on what exactly it does.

The point, though, is that I don't think the git hook is using this version of `cd`. I base this on the output of this command: `shopt -s extdebug ; declare -F cd` (which I found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/283352/how-do-you-run-a-shell-command-script-automatically-when-entering-cd-ing-a-direc)). When I run it myself, the output is `cd 14 /Users/imclean/.rvm/scripts/cd` - showing where RVM defines `cd`, whereas if I have my git hook run and echo that same command, it outputs a blank line.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use [Git Hooks](https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks).

There's a post-checkout hook that can run shell script, so you can cheat and just `cd .` to have rvm recheck the version for you.

Comment: So I've managed to add a post-checkout hook, and I can tell it's running, but having it run `cd .` doesn't actually do anything. I assume the hook isn't running in the current process, or something like that.

Comment: That's weird, hooks don't run as a subprocess or anything. It's possible `cd .` doesn't refresh rvm? In that case, I'd try your `cd .. && cd project_directory`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to work either, once it's in a git hook.

Comment: I know this questions is some months old. But I've finally gotten around to jot down the steps I use, to deal with different RVM gemsets for git branches. Maybe it could help you. http://is.gd/pao3ZZ

Comment: Git hooks seem to run in a child shell. Any environment variable you change in the hook will not be copied back to your original shell.

Answer (score 0):

Git hooks probably cannot solve your problem, because they run in a child shell.

It might not be the prettiest solution, but I just defined an alias for git checkout :

```
gco(){
    git checkout "$@"
    cd .
    echo "Now using : "
    ruby -v
}
```

You can just copy paste it into your shell to test it :

```
> gco master                                                                                           
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Now using : 
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]

> gco jruby                                                                      
Switched to branch 'jruby'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/jruby'.
Now using : 
jruby 9.0.5.0 (2.2.3) 2016-01-26 7bee00d Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.101-b13 on 1.8.0_101-b13 +jit [linux-amd64]
```

If you're happy with this shell function, just paste it in ~/.profile